# CSS scroll page to long

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am currently working on developing a mobile site, which is a simplified version of a desktop site. I have developed a mobile web page where you can press a button to scroll to the next section of the web page. However the page is supposed to stop scrolling once you reach the bottom of this 2nd page. However the scrolling continues, any suggestions or idea on how to limit the amount of scrolling would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<scroll-container>
    <scroll-page id="page1">
        {content}
    </scroll-page>
    <scroll-page id="page2">
        {content}
    </scroll-page>
</scroll-container>
```

CSS:

```
scroll-container 
{ 
     display: block; 
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100%; 
     overflow-y: scroll; 
     margin: auto; 
}

scroll-page 
{ 
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center; 
    height: 640px; 
    width: 100%; 
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto; 
}
```

[First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaS4p.png)
[Unwanted white space under page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et3Lv.png)

Comment: Hi @Edev, I would suggest you to use this plugin. 
https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Here you can set the scroll amount according to your requirement.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly you want to restrict ability to scroll once the end of the 2nd page is reached? Why no to hide subsequent sections via media-queries?

Comment: @Runnick That's correct. I have hidden sections via media queries already but this unwanted white space still remains.

Comment: It's difficult to understand without having some visual reference

Comment: Have just added two pictures so try and give a better visual representation.